# Condition Vairable and notify_all

Tags: c++, multithreading

In the following code (taken from cpp reference with an extra cout added) why don't we see `...finished waiting.`  after the first `cv.notify_all`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex cv_m; // This mutex is used for three purposes:
                 // 1) to synchronize accesses to i
                 // 2) to synchronize accesses to std::cerr
                 // 3) for the condition variable cv
int i = 0;

void waits()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
    std::cerr << "Waiting... \n";
    cv.wait(lk, []{return i == 1;});
    std::cerr << "...finished waiting. i == 1\n";
}

void signals()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
        std::cerr << "Notifying...\n";
    }
    cv.notify_all();

    std::cerr << "I should see i here...\n";

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
        i = 1;
        std::cerr << "Notifying again...\n";
    }
    cv.notify_all();
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(waits), t2(waits), t3(waits), t4(signals);
    t1.join(); 
    t2.join(); 
    t3.join();
    t4.join();
}
```

Output:

```
Waiting... 
Waiting... 
Waiting... 
Notifying...
I should see i here...
Notifying again...
...finished waiting. i == 1
...finished waiting. i == 1
...finished waiting. i == 1
```

Comment: By the way that's a `cerr` not a `cout` and you broke the synchronisation of `cerr` by `cv_m`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it *hasn't* finished waiting.

You told it to wait until `i` is `1`, but it is still `0`. So it will keep waiting.

This is the case even though you "notified" it — you notified it that a change happened, but actually a change *didn't* happen, so it went back to waiting.

`notify()` is not `ignore_the_predicate_i_gave_you_and_stop_waiting()`.

Answer (score 3):

Because this line:

```
cv.wait(lk, []{return i == 1;});
```

you passed a predicate, thus it will wake up only if the predicate returns `true`. After first `notify_all()`, the predicate is not satisfied.